# If a question makes an erroneous assumption, should we close it or attempt to answer by solving the assumption?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, closed-questions

A (now deleted) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128506/how-do-interfaces-get-their-power) was asked a few minutes ago.

The question (as I read it) seems to be "I don't understand how language feature X produces effect E, can someone explain?". The problem is that feature X doesn't produce effect E, it's another feature Y that produces effect E.

In other words, the OP made a mistake with the question: he/she made an assumption that didn't hold and he/she phrased the question based on that assumption. Clearly the OP is at that annoying spot where you want to know about something but you're unable to phrase a question about it completely correctly yet.

Now on one hand, if the premise of a question is wrong, then the question itself likely won't make sense and thus won't have an answer. I suspect it was on that ground that a few users closed and then deleted the question. Fair enough, I see where they're coming from and I respect their judgement on the site in general.

But on the other hand, I can't ignore the feeling that I (and a few others, apparently) managed to see through the OP's confusion and gave an answer that attempted to solve the root of that confusion.

Is there a community consensus on what should be done in these cases? Should we attempt to solve the confusion that's apparent from the false assumptions, or should we instead close the question?

---

I am not talking about the OP asking for help with a solution when the problem should have been different (XY problem). I'm talking about the OP asking for an explanation about a concept and being confused about the mechanisms behind the concept -- with no problems or solutions involved. Thus, I think this Meta question is not a duplicate of the suggested ones.

Comment: Your title and body are asking different questions.  A question with a false premise and an unclear question are very different.

Comment: Also, for this specific case, the question wasn't closed as being unclear, it was closed as being too broad, so your assertion that you think you understand what the question is asking isn't inconsistent with that close reason.

Comment: @Servy It's true that a false premise and an unclear question are very different. But in the body of the question I've specified that I didn't find the question unclear at all (but it was marked as unclear by others during its first close vote).

Comment: Again, the question was closed as being too broad, and that looks quite right to me.  It wasn't closed as being unclear.

Comment: @Servy I was referring to the first round of closing (before it got re-opened and then re-closed), but I'll edit to remove the reference to "unclear" if it takes away the focus from what I'm asking.

Comment: Isn't this what we call a X Y problem?

Comment: @Renan According to [the canonical question on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), the XY problem is asking about your solution rather than about your problem. While I can see how the confusion I'm describing is analogous to the XY problem, the question I linked to does not involve a solution and so I don't think that the same answers would necessarily be applicable.

Answer (score 11):

***TL;DR:*** These questions don't always deserve closure - inform the OP about the error in the assumption instead.

These are the reasons for closing a question:

- It's been asked and answered before (duplicate)
- It's not about programming [as we define it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (off-topic)
- We can't tell what's being asked (unclear what you're asking)
- There are lots of possible answers, or a complete answer would be ***EXTREMELY*** long (too broad)
- Its answers are likely to be more opinionated than "factated" (primarily opinion-based)

Since none of these reasons necessarily fit to a question based on an erroneous assumption, it's the best thing to do to point out that the OP is assuming it wrong and explain how things work in reality.

Comment: Is it possible to get suspended because of a pun?

Comment: Is "factated" your pun? It's not really a pun, just an end-rhyme. And it reads way too much like "lactated".

Comment: I agree with @CodyGray that "factated" isn't a pun, but in trying to think of one that would fit in your sentence I learned a new word: ["factitious."](https://www.google.com/search?q=factitious&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 7):

Let me describe what I had seen on this particular question, since I was one of the people that could both understand what was being asked, *edited* the question to make it clearer, and voted to reopen the question based on that understanding.

The OP is asking a question about how Java's interfaces work. That is to say, they were curious how by implementing the `Runnable` interface, then their thread would be table to take up and run whatever was in their `run` method.  In this **specific** example, the fundamental misunderstanding is that `Runnable` doesn't run threads; `Thread` accepts a `Runnable` for it to then execute.

However, if we were to clear up the confusion and use a different interface, or create our own (the typical `Fruit` -> `Banana`, `Apple`, `Grape` or `Animal` -> `Dog`, `Cat`, `Zebra`), we could peel away the misunderstanding and get at the crux of the question:  how would I, by using the interface, be able to specify different behavior?

To be blunt, this question likely *already* has an answer somewhere, since it's a fairly common and entry-level question when one programs to an interface.  However, the main thing that struck out at me was that the question was closed as "unclear".  The question being asked *seemed* crystal-clear to me, given that the crux of it hinged on interfaces, and not *necessarily* just the `Runnable` interface.

When the question was closed, I remarked that I [too] could understand what was being asked, edited it for grammar, and cast a reopen vote.  This is where things get muddled.

I don't disagree that there's probably a dupe for the question - [I even say as much, for goodness' sake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128506/how-do-interfaces-get-their-power#comment65602884_39128506) - but that dupe **should be exposed here** and the OP should at least be able to find a hint to help them along, as opposed to hearing that their question is "terrible".

My belief is that we didn't clearly understand the root of the problem; we only saw a broken metaphor of the actual question, and reacted to that instead.  I feel we reacted too quickly and deleted the question in haste, and in spite of its misunderstanding.  I stress that yes, there's probably a duplicate answer out there, but **linking to that is better than closing *and* deleting the question.**

The OP should be able to clarify what they mean, but in this scenario, this is what I feel editing is for.  We have the power to edit the question if we understand it, and allow for those who come after us to actually see if the question is good.  If we outright delete the question, we're denied that chance and we deny this question any sort of chance at all to get better.  The user then also faces repercussions because they couldn't *quite* explain it 100% clearly, but in a few people's opinions, they came within the 95th percentile.

As for a community consensus?  I don't know what to say about it.  We're given these powers to ensure that the quality of our questions remains high, but there are cases in which I do personally feel that these powers are taken a bit...far.  I'd rather see an environment in which questions like this do have a period to cool off to allow the OP (or others) to come back and edit the question to help it along, as opposed to letting it be deleted, since that's *very* tough to overturn alone.

Comment: You contridict yourself by saying that the question is crystal clear, and also saying that you need the author to edit it in order for you to understand what they mean enough to answer it.  If you need the OP to clarify it to understand what they're asking, then it is, by definition, unclear.

Comment: @Servy:  You seem to see things in black and white here.  I state that the OP should be able to clarify, not that they *needed* to.  In this scenario, I should probably shoulder some blame since I could understand what was being asked well enough that I *had* started an answer, but I did not close the loop with the broken metaphor of an example that was used because I wanted to preserve intent.  I didn't require the OP to clarify anything.  I merely want to leave them that option.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** If you cannot find a valid close reason you must leave the question open. If the question is valid you may answer it. If the question isn't useful just downvote and move on.

**Should we close it?**

Of course only if a valid close reason applies. There may be duplicates, there may be a complete minimal example missing, answers are likely to be opiniated or the question may be unclear. If you find that this is the case, good, close vote.

Such questions based on misunderstandings are probably more likely to get closed, but you have to check each single case and don't try so hard, that you choose a close reason that doesn't really apply just because you want that question to be closed.

**Should we attempt to answer it?**

A sufficient answer would be to point out the logical fallacy/ wrong assumption and then concluding with the impossibility of the claimed behavior. This should be simple. In general, answer ontopic questions if you want to answer them. Nobody is holding you back.

**What else matters?**

Likely these questions are not useful. After all there are endless ways to get assumptions wrong. Likely most of them are neither relevant for others nor give any meaningful insight into programming. This is a reason to downvote and to move on.

However, there might be a few cases of "famous misunderstandings" that may result in highly upvoted questions which are open and answered. Don't have an example right now but I'm quite sure they exist.

Comment: What is the S in MSCVE?

Comment: @dorukayhan Foremost it stands for itself. :) Thanks for pointing out.