# Should one delete a question if it considers things that are proven wrong?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72698852/) on SO, and while at the time, I thought the `mkdir` command didn't work, later, I realized that was not the issue, and the problem was caused by something else in my script.

What should I do with the question that is asking of a problem which does not exist? 
Close it? Or mark it "irrelevant"? Or delete it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a question makes an erroneous assumption, should we close it or attempt to answer by solving the assumption?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333111/if-a-question-makes-an-erroneous-assumption-should-we-close-it-or-attempt-to-an)

Comment: Seems like you are saying that that the question is either *"Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"* or *"Needs debugging details"*

Comment: @GinoMempin it is close to the situation, but here, noone have a chance of knowing anything about what really is causing the problem.

Comment: @Larnu I think Yes, that's sums it up... How to flag it as such?

Comment: You can either edit the question (this is preferred) to give a proper minimal reproducible example while making sure that it doesn't invalidate the existing answer or if you feel that it was caused by a typo you can delete it (Since it will probably get deleted some time after it closed)

Comment: Other people can use that close reason.  If you realize it yourself, it usually makes sense to delete, unless there's some salvageable part with likely value to future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question has no answers and you realized that it is incorrect/unhelpful, you can simply delete it.

Once there are answers posted this might no longer be possible. In that case you can leave a comment below your question explaining why and prompt other users to close it as "Not reproducible". You can also flag your own question for closure, in this case:

Flag -> Needs Improvement -> A community-specific reason -> Not reproducible or was caused by a typo

Closed questions with no up-voted or accepted answers will eventually get automatically deleted by the system.

Answer (score 11):

You should delete the question if it won't be useful to anybody else.  Generally after some time has passed you can tell if it's been useful by noting if it has any upvotes.

Comment: I kindof like that this leaves the responsability into users to decide themselves. I am also scared of the result, but SO seems to be doing fine with this system.